# Get handle of View of first group of Expandable ListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

In an `Activity`, how to do I get access to the first group view of `Expandable ListView` ?

Here is what I am doing:

```
public int getFirstVisibleGroup() {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "getFirstVisibleGroup called");
        int firstVis = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "firstVis = " + firstVis);
        long packedPosition = listView.getExpandableListPosition(firstVis);
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "packedPosition = " + packedPosition);
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "firstVisibleGroup = " + ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition));
        return ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);
    }

    public View getGroupView(ExpandableListView listView, int groupPosition) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "getGroupView called");
        int flatPosition = listView.getFlatListPosition(groupPosition);
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "flatPosition = " + flatPosition);
        int first = getFirstVisibleGroup();
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "first = " + first);
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "returning child at position " + (flatPosition - first));
        return listView.getChildAt(flatPosition - first);
    }
```

And I call it with:

```
View view = getGroupView(listView, 0);
```

Ultimately it becomes `listView.getChildAt(0)`. And the `view` returned is null.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: when are you trying to call `listView.getChildAt(0)`? Is that between onCreate/onResume or after the user clicked on the view?

Comment: @Budius in `onCreate()`, I do a service call and when the result of service call has come, I update the `Expandable ListView` and after that I call the above method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the adapter based views (ListView, GridView, RecyclerView) only add the views to itself after they have been laid out on the screen. So that they can calculate appropriate sizing and query for enough child views.

Because of that, during `onCreate` you'll never never any views. That means that if you want to interact with some of its child views, it must happen later on.

One suitable approach is to use the `OnPreDraw` listener. That is right before the system calls `draw(canvas)` on the views. Example:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(bundle){
        ... build your layout and your listview

        // during onCreate you add a PreDrawListener
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreDraw() {

        ... do your logic here !!!


        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this); // remove itself, you only need the fist pass
        return true; // must return true, or else the system won't draw anything.
    }

}
```

Comment: I am still getting the `view` as `null`. Plus, `onPreDraw()` gets called even before the network response comes.

Comment: oh... I guess I missed the part where u said about network. But the idea is the same, it's a `PreDraw` it will get called right before it draws again on the screen. That means for your case you should `addOnPreDrawListener` right after calling `setAdapter` or `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: Ok. I will try that.